# Best way to instantly check proximity to one of two locations in Android?

Tags: android, location, proximity

I'm writing an app that utilizes parse for cloud data storage.  I recently was told that the people I'm writing this for are opening a second location, and would like to know which location a user is checking in to/recording data at.  I've found the google code at:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

that defines how to use geofencing, as well as how to get the last known gps/network location.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

But I can't tell if either one of these are what I need. Basically I'm trying to do the following:

1. User starts app
2. User clicks "Check In" to check in to a class at the gym
3. When the "check in" activity loads, the user can click a class.  At this point in time I'd like to know if the user is say...within 5 miles of a central lat/long.   The two locations are around 20 miles apart, so a rough estimate putting them even within a few miles should be fine (are they in Sunnyvale or San Jose?)
4. When user clicks a class, the check-in gets sent to a Parse database, along with the location (either one city or the other)

I'm not sure if geofencing is proper for this case, as i just need to know rough area from a point..but the basic location getting sample doesn't seem to show how to check when the phone is near a point.

To this point, I've found the following:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html

This seems to be the best option, except it constantly checks for "distance" from the set point, and I need to tell once if the user is near one or the other locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
Location me   = new Location("");
Location dest = new Location("");

me.setLatitude(myLat);
me.setLongitude(myLong);

dest.setLatitude(destLat);
dest.setLongitude(destLong);

float dist = me.distanceTo(dest);
```

You can then repeat for the second location and store both distances then compare to see the smallest.

Comment: Thanks!  I found the haversine formula, but when I tried implementing it with Geopoints, I always get some noclassdef error.  Let me try this and I'll accept this.  This is simple too, since I'm not really trying to geofence or prox alert the user.. just want a simple check to see if they're by one point or the other.

Comment: Yeah I made an effort to implement Haversine in my app but given the relatively close proximity of the points it proved to be unnecessary. For distances in double or even triple digit miles that should be fine :-)

Comment: Scott.  Accepted the answer, as this worked well enough for my use.  Haversine was a pain, this returns approximate meters, and since the two locations are ~20 miles or more apart, as long as it's within say 4 miles (usually getting a cell tower location instead of the gps coordinates) it is "accurate enough" for this usage.  Thanks for the help!